# beacon not scanning when app closed from recent apps using alt beacon libaray

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon

I am developing an app to scan beacons using altbecaon library. Every time I am having different issues when I change my scenario. I don't know what is the reason. Everything working fine. But the problem is when I close my app from swiping away from recent apps and then open again, my app is not scanning. Then I just switched off my beacon to make exit region method to run. After that, it's scanning as usual. I want the app to scan even after I close my app from the recent app and open again. Please help me, kindly.

**The code of scanning fragment is:**

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("scannerfragment","oncraeteview");

        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scanning, container, false);

        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(a);

        ArrayList<OfferPromotion>  offersPromotions=new ArrayList<>();
        scanningPageAdapter = new ScanningPageAdapter(a,offersPromotions,ScanningPage.this);


        recycler_scanner.setAdapter(scanningPageAdapter);
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();

        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()
                .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));


        beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(3001);
        beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(2001);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(2001);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(3001);
        identifier = Identifier.parse("E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0"); //beacon 1

        region = new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", identifier, null, null);

        Log.w(TAG,"application"+Constantsforbinding.application_stateregion);



        beaconManager.bind(this);

               return view;

    }

@Override
    public Context getApplicationContext() {
        return getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void unbindService(ServiceConnection serviceConnection) {
        getActivity().unbindService(serviceConnection);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean bindService(Intent intent, ServiceConnection serviceConnection, int i) {
        return getActivity().bindService(intent, serviceConnection, i);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {

        try{
            beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();
        }
        catch (RemoteException  e){
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
            Toast.makeText(a, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        addmonitor();
        addrangenotifieer();
        beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(monitorNotifier);
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(rangeNotifier);


    }

     public void addmonitor(){
    monitorNotifier=new MonitorNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time!");
            startbeaconranging(region);
            nobeacon=0;

        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(final Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "No beacons..waiting for 25 seconds to confirm");
            beacondetected=false;
            stopranginbeacon(region);
            if(a!=null){
                Toast.makeText(a, "No beacons..wait for 25 seconds to confirm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                a.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                if(beacondetected){
                                    /*Toast.makeText(a, "Beacon detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                                    Log.i(TAG, ""+beacondetected);


                                }
                                else {
                                    try {

                                        lay_no_offer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        ((NavigationActivity)a).setAlreadyScannerlaunched(false);
                                        Log.i(TAG, "no beacons for last 25 seconds"+beacondetected);
                                        Toast.makeText(a, "no beacons for last 25 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        tv_status.setText("No beacons detected..scanning");
                                        lay_having_offer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }


                            }
                        },25000);

                    }
                });
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state);
            if(state==1){
                tv_status.setText("Scanning...wait for 15 seconds");

            }else if(state==0){

                tv_status.setText("No beacons..scanning");
            }

        }
    };
}
public void addrangenotifieer(){
    rangeNotifier = new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, final Region region) {
            if (beacons.size() > 0) {

                beacondetected=true;
                Collections.sort((List<Beacon>) beacons, new Comparator<Beacon>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Beacon o1, Beacon o2) {
                        return Double.compare(o2.getDistance(),( o1.getDistance()));
                    }


                });

                mac1=((List<Beacon>) beacons).get(0).getBluetoothAddress();
                nobeacon=0;

                if (a != null) {
                    call_offers_api(mac1);

                }
                Log.i(TAG, "The first beacon I see is about "+nobeacon+((List<Beacon>) beacons).get(0).getBluetoothAddress()+"");
            }
            else {



            }
        }
    };
}

@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        stopranginbeacon(region);
        Stopmonitoringbecaon(region);
        beaconManager.removeAllMonitorNotifiers();
        beaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers();

        beaconManager.unbind(this);


        Log.d("scannerfragment","ondestroyview");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Understand that didEnterRegion only fires once when a beacon matching the region comes into view.  The library remembers the in/out status of your region even if you stop and restart your app.  So didEnterRegion will not fire a second time just because you restart your app -- the beacon(s) must actually go out of range for a bit and reappear for it to fire a second time.

Starting ranging in didEnterRegion can be problematic due to the above. Instead, start ranging in onBeaconServiceConnect or didDetermineStateForRegion.  Both of those callbacks always fire on app restart.

Comment: Thank you.It works now.i removed the startrangingbeacon method and put in serviceconnect .Also i am using the latest libarary.